# How can make the Radio-Button to be active when click and change the color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I created a Radio-Button and customize it as an actual button, How can I change the `background-color` of the clicked Radio Button? Like for example, If I Click the first choice, it will be highlighted

So this is my UI, it shows the choices here

[image]

```
<FormControl sx={{width: '100%'}} >
      <RadioGroup
      aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
      name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      sx={{width: '100%', display:'flex', gap:1 }}
      >
         <FormControlLabel 
               value="male" 
               control={<Radio sx={{ display: 'none' }} />} 
               label={
                   <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                       Male
                   </Typography>
                     }
               sx={{
               display: 'flex', 
               alignItems: 'center', 
               width: '100%', 
               justifyContent: 'center',
               color: 'blue',
              '&:hover':{
              backgroundColor: '#03a9f4',
              color: 'white'
               },

                 }}/>

              <FormControlLabel 
        value="female" 
        control={<Radio sx={{ display: 'none' }} />} 
            label={
            <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            Female
            </Typography>
           }
            sx={{
            display: 'flex', 
            alignItems: 'center', 
            width: '100%', 
            justifyContent: 'center',
            color: 'blue',
           '&:hover':{
            backgroundColor: '#03a9f4',
            color: 'white'
            },

            }}/>                                
            </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `checked` property. If the value passed is true, the component appears selected.

You may try -

```
<FormControlLabel 
    value="male" 
    control={<Radio sx={{ display: 'none' }} />} 
    checked={value === 'male'} // Or try checked=true
    ...
```

Same for the other one. See the [official documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control-label/)  for reference.